# NoClassDefFoundError BytecodeVisitor when deploying my own Java rule implementation

Tags: sonarqube

I have created a new rule implementation in Java.  The POM includes the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
        <type>sonar-plugin</type>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The new rule extends

```
org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.BytecodeVisitor
```

which IntelliJ IDEA resolves as being in

```
org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:java-squid:3.1
```

However, upon deploying the plugin artifact to a brand new installation of Sonar 5.1.2 I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/java/bytecode/visitor/BytecodeVisitor
```

To deploy, I put the plugin.jar into the "plugins/downloads" folder and attempt to start Sonar,

Can someone confirm that I am using the correct dependencies for a plugin targeting Sonar 5.1.2 ?

I observe that my plugin has no META-INF/lib/, whereas some larger plugins do include JAR files in that location.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Robin.

Answer (score 0):

I was completely off the mark.

I was trying to deploy a Rule as if it was a Plugin.

The correct structure is described here:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+Plugins